# How to wrap validation messge on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I added TextFormField validation message..Everything working good. But All text not displayed.

```
Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0),
            child: TextFormField(
              validator: (value) {
                if (value.isEmpty) {
               return 'The password you entered does not meet the minimum requirement. Please refer the Password Policy for more details.';
              },
              obscureText: true,
              controller: confirmPasswordController,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                labelText: AppTranslations.of(context)
                    .text("passwordpage_username"),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

[image]

Comment: Try to Use `expanded`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Expanded(
   child: Container(
     padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
     margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0),
     child: TextFormField(
          validator: (value) {
            if (value.isEmpty) {
           return 'The password you entered does not meet the minimum requirement.\n Please refer the Password Policy for more details.';
          },
          obscureText: true,
          controller: confirmPasswordController,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            labelText: AppTranslations.of(context)
                .text("passwordpage_username"),
          ),
        ),
       )
      ),
```